# Create random sampling point in each grid's cell

Tags: qgis, point, qgis-processing, random, sampling

I would like to know how to create an X number of random points in each grid cell.

I'm using data from a DEM layer, which contains information about elevation. I used this information to obtain slope and aspect. Then I created a grid (each cell with 1000 units size) with the objective of randomly sampling each cell (with one, two points, doesn't matter) so I could obtain an average value of slope and aspect for each location (location = grid cell).

[image: My current project looks like this]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write Random in the `Processing toolbox`, you will find that there are many Random Points inside polygon tools exist in QGIS as you can see below:

[image]

You can test which one will fit your needs either `Random Points inside Polygon (Fixed)` or `Random Points inside Polygon (Variable)`.

Example:

Using `Random Points inside Polygon (Fixed)`, you need to specify the number of points: 2 as you want. For minimum distance I put 0.001 in this example, but you can put also Zero (0) and it should work.

[image]

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: That seems to be what I want! Just a small question: Minimum distance is a value you give to say that you want points separated by at least that value is that correct? I used 1000 units (same size of each cell) and I got a ridiculous amount of points! Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake. You can keep the value of minimum distance as Zero (0), and it should give you correct result. I will update my answer.